# Given an interger N and an integer G, find all pairs of element <=N having GCD greater than G

Tags: java, math, greatest-common-divisor

Given an integer N and another integer G, find all pairs of integer (i,j) such that gcd (i,j) > G where 0<=i,j<=N.

The easiest solution is to run two loops and check gcd of each pair which will result in O(n^2) complexity.

The second approach I thought of was to run loop starting from G+1 till N/2, and for each i , get all its multiples. But this will not generate all pairs.

```
        List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> ll = new LinkedList<>();
        for(int i=g+1;i<=n/2;i++){
            List<Integer> l = new LinkedList<>();
            for(int j=i+i;j<=n;j+=i){
                ll.add(new Pair<>(i, j));
            }
        }
```

The third approach is to consider all elements from G+1 to N , and for each element get all their divisors > G.

```
        List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> ll = new LinkedList<>();
        for(int j=g+1;j<=n;j++) {
            for (int i = g+1; i <= Math.sqrt(j); i++) {
                if (i != j && j % i == 0 && (j/i)!= j) {
                    if (j / i == i && i>g) // check if divisors are equal
                        ll.add(new Pair<>(i, j));
                    else {
                        if(i > g) ll.add(new Pair<>(i, j));
                        if (j / i > g) ll.add(new Pair<>(j / i, j));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I am looking for a more optimised solution. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this algorithm to generate your pairs: start from G+1 and for each integer till N/2, create a list of multipliers which are smaller than N. For instance, if G=3 and N=19, you will start with:

- 4: 4, 8, 12, 16
- 5: 5, 10, 15
- 6: 6, 12, 18
- 7: 7, 14
- 8: 8, 16
- 9: 9, 18

You need to make the pairs from this list, by selecting any pairing (and not including doubles): 4:8, 4:12, 4:16, 8:12, 8:16, 12:16, 5:10, 5:15, 10:15, 6:12, 6:18, 12:18, 7:14, 9:18. You can do this one group of multipliers at a time, going from G+1 to N/2. The complexity of this code is O((N/2-G)*K) where K is the length of the multiplier list, at most N/(G+1). You could imporve this further by skipping numbers which already appeared in the multiplier lists (for instance, we don't need to deal with 8 in our example).

The code to generate it is simple:

```
int n = 1000;
int g = 1;
boolean[] skipMultiplier = new boolean[n+1];
Set<Pair<Integer,Integer>> pairs = new HashSet<Pair<Integer,Integer>>();
for (int i=g+1; i<n/2+1 ;i++) {
    List<Integer> multipliers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int j=2; j< n/i+1 ; j++) {
        if (skipMultiplier[i]) {
            continue;
        }
        multipliers.add(i*j);
        skipMultiplier[i*j] = true;
        Pair<Integer,Integer> pair = new Pair<Integer,Integer>(i,i*j);
        pairs.add(pair);
    }
    for (int j=0; j<multipliers.size()-1; j++) {
        for (int k=j+1; k<multipliers.size(); k++) {
            Pair<Integer,Integer> pair = 
                new Pair<Integer,Integer> (multipliers.get(j), multipliers.get(k));
            pairs.add(pair);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You left out the pairs (x,x) that would also be solutions. For example (17, 17).

Comment: I thought i!=j, but if not it's easy to add them.

Comment: @Assafs thanks for the solution, but I need more optimised one. The suggested solution takes >10s if g=1 and n=10000. I am looking for something which can reduce it to a range of 10-200ms.

Comment: @umang OK, thanks for the feedback. I have an optimization in mind that may help speed things up. I'll try to update it here when I test it.

Comment: @umang I fixed the code/algorithm with two changes:1) I'm using a hash Set to avoid duplicates instead of going over the list 2) I'm using a skipping array of booleans to ignore numbers I already went through. It improved my times significantly.